# What is the relationship of the radius of curvatures of Bertrand mate?

Tags: differential-geometry

For plannar Bertrand mate, we have $r_1+d=r_2$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the radius of curves' curvatures respectively, and d is their distance (along principal normal). Is this relationship still holds for all of the spatial Bertrand mates?

Comment: The only planar Bertrand mates are circles. It seems rash to jump to a conjecture based on one example. Have you tried testing your conjecture for the simplest possible space curves — circular helices?

Comment: (Oh, and lines, I suppose, for which there is no radius of curvature.)

Comment: Planar Bertrand mates are only circles and lines??? who told you this? any plannar curves satisfy Bertrand mates.

Comment: Ah, i hadn’t thought about it before. I was using $a\kappa+b\tau =1$ as characterizing curves that admit Bertrand mates. I forgot the hypothesis $\tau\ne 0$. You're not quite right, though. You need $1-d\kappa$ everywhere nonzero. ... My fundamental question stays: Have you computed a single 3-D example before asking?